# dplyr sql joins

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

Consider the following SQL:

```
    SELECT D.product_name
      FROM business.payment P
 LEFT JOIN dim.product_name D 
        ON D.product_id = P.product_id
```

The query returns the list of product_names that are in the payment table and does so based on a join.

How would something like this be replicated in dplyr without pulling into memory? I'm working with a database connection.

I tried the following, but to no avail:

```
product_name <- 
  business %>% 
  tbl('dim_product') 

business %>% 
  tbl('payment') %>% 
  left_join(product_name, by = 'product_id') %>% 
  select(product_name) %>% 
  collect()
```

I've searched quite a big and no one seems to have addressed this.

Thanks!

Comment: R stores all objects in memory. So if you're using `dplyr` you're using it on objects and therefore in memory. Having said that, you can use arbitrary SQL in `dplyr`, e.g. `tbl(my_db_extract_now_in_memory, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))` but it's always going to be in memory.

Comment: I'm trying to do this strictly using dplyr.  Laziness should not bring them into memory until `collect()` triggers.

Comment: Doing it all in `dplyr` is no problem but I'm just saying it's going to be in memory once it's extracted. Note this is no different then query a DB through R via any other means, such as by `RODBC`. The one way that it wouldn't be in memory is if you used `RPostgres` or `RODBC`, etc to send a SQL query and just used it to create a new table *within the database* and never exported the data to R.

Comment: That's fine. The point is to prevent that before the final pull because there's large amounts of data.

Answer (score 5):

This is a while after the fact but maybe you're still looking or curious for a `dplyr` verb based option. I was working on the same issue for my work and came across your (sort of) unanswered question. Below works for me when I run it against an MSSQL database using `DBI` and `odbc` packages.

I selected the columns of interest from the tables before joining as that is generally best practice when querying databases. `dplyr` join functions will do a natural join by default so you might not have to provide the `by` argument explicitly.

```
db_con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = odbc::odbc(),
  dsn = <data source name>
)

db_con %>%
  tbl("table1") %>%
  select(col1, col2, col3) %>%
  left_join(
    db_con %>% tbl("table2") %>% select(col3,  col4, col5)
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use arbitrary SQL in `dplyr`:

```
tbl(my_data, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))
```

Note this is no different than querying a DB through R via any other means, such as by `RODBC`.

Of course, the extracted data will *always* be in memory once it's imported into R via the query. The one way that it wouldn't be in memory at all is if you used `RPostgres` or `RODBC`, etc to send a SQL query and just used it to create a new table within the database and never exported the data to R.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to do this with dplyr so I can only use one language. 
`How would something like this be replicated in dplyr without pulling into memory?`

Comment: @PhillipBlack What are you talking about? The code in my answer **is** `dplyr` and I answered your question regarding doing it without pulling it into memory. Like I said, you use arbitrary SQL within `dplyr` as in my example. See `?tbl` and Read The Fine Manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html

Comment: @PhillipBlack So, to recap, as you mentioned `dplyr` can wait until the last second via laziness, i.e. it only pulls the final extract (not the intermediate tables) into memory, which is precisely what happens in the code in my answer. For absolutely nothing to be pulled into memory then (obviously) the only solution is to use `RODBC` or any similar package to query your data into a new created table within your DB, thus by-passing R entirely.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I'm trying not to use _any_ SQL regardless of what it's wrapped in.

Comment: @Hack-R, thanks but I don't understand. When I run this ```library(tidyverse) ; data(iris); my_data <- iris ;  tbl(my_data, sql("SELECT * FROM my_data"))``` I get this error: ```Error in UseMethod("tbl") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "data.frame"```, and the same error when I do this: ```Error in UseMethod("tbl") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "data.frame"```

Comment: @RasmusLarsen Yea that would throw a data type error. Sorry, it's been a couple of years. Try this: `download.file(url = "https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/2292171",destfile = "a.sqlite", mode = "wb"); mammals <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "a.sqlite"); tbl(mammals, sql("SELECT year, species_id, plot_id FROM surveys"))`