# Join multiple tables from SQL database using dplyr

Tags: mysql, sql, r, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out how to use dplyr to do my SQL queries when multiple tables need to be joined. For example, if we connect to a database using `pool`:

```
require(pool)
require(dplyr)

my_db <- dbPool(
  RMySQL::MySQL(), 
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)
```

Before joining tables we have to do:

```
city <- my_db %>% tbl("City")
country <- my_db %>% tbl("Country")
clang <- my_db %>% tbl("CountryLanguage")

join_data <- left_join(city, country, by = c("CountryCode" = "Code")) %>%
  left_join(., clang)
```

Is this the correct way? Or does a method exists that means tables do not have to be manually predefined?

Alternatively, it looks like from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864427/dplyr-sql-joins) that arbitrary SQL code can be used with `dplyr`. However, perhaps there is no point switching to `dplyr` if I am just going to copy and paste existing queries?

Comment: *Is this the correct way?*...only you can determine that. If no error and results are what you want, then yes!

Comment: Consider having your database engine do the querying and not on client in R.

Comment: Normally I would just write an SQL query string and use e.g. dbGetQuery() to fetch the results. I'm trying to understand if using dplyr to interact with a database is effecient or worthwhile when I need to combine data from multiple tables (maybe 5-10). The above would work but surely isn't a good way to do it?

Comment: Once again, doing work in `dplyr` runs processing locally in RAM on your client machine. Calling a query with `dbGetQuery` runs processing in remote database on server with resultset fetched locally. Use R for your analytical data work and databases with what it does best: set-based retrieval and manipulation.

Comment: in his case the work is done on the remote db thanks to `dbplyr` though, and as he hasn't collected the data yet, as far as I understand, no query has run yet

Comment: Thanks. Would you make multiple joins in the way I did in the question?